# Android Auto "voice commands are not available right now"

Tags: voice-command, android-auto

I am using Android Auto with my Samsung Galaxy A10s (Android 11) connected to my 2022 Subaru Outback.

Whenever I try to used Google voice commands I get the message on the display "voice commands aren't available right now". This has been happening for weeks, and happens whether I use the car's talk button or the on-display "voice" button (microphone symbol).

Software and apps appear to be up to date. I cleared the cache of Google Assistant and Android Auto apps on the phone. Non-voice functions with Android Auto appear to be working.

Any known way to fix this?